# A default dropdown value only renders after an initial input

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, async.js

I have an input form which has a dropdown menu and I am trying to set a default value. This value is passed down from a parent component and is received from an async function (which I think may have a part). The async function renders the user's name in an h1 and displays above the form properly. It also acts as the condition to determine the default value according to one's name. I have tried to use state, in multiple components and always end up with “Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.” Please take a look below and help me figure it out and if you could provide some topics on the concept I am missing here, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
const dashboard = (props)=>{
    const getName = async ()=>{
        try{~GETS DATA~
            setName(parsedData[0].user_name}
        catch{error}
    }

    let defaultSchool
 //switch statement chooses the value for the default in dropdown menu based on the name from GET
    switch(name){
        case "user1":
        defaultSchool= "Cool School"
        case "user2":
        defaultSchool= "Another School
    }
  return(
      <div>
          <InputForm defaultSchool= defaultSchool />
      </div>
  )
}
```

Above is the parent component which passes this data down to the next component which contains an input form.

```
const InputForm = ({defaultSchool})=>{
    const [school, setSchool]= useState(defaultSchool)
    const [some_state, setSome_State] = useState("")
    // numerous other states associated with the form with no significant relevance

        const onSubmitForm = async e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            try{~normally POSTS data~}
            catch{error}
        }
     
      return(
             <h1 className="text-center my-5 input 
                                   title">Input Form</h1>
             <form className="mt-5" onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
             {/* DATE  */}
                    <input type="date"  name="connection_date" 
                                      placeholder="Date of Contact" 
                                       className="form-control" 
                                       value={connection_date} 
                         onChange={e => setDate(e.target.value)}/>
             {/* SCHOOL  */}
                 <select  type="text" name="school" 
                                       placeholder="School" className="form-control mt-3" 
                                       defaultValue={defaultSchool} value={defaultSchool} 
                                       onChange={e => setSchool(e.target.value)}>
                         // <option value="NADA" disabled>Choose your school</option>
                         // this is a default option i tried with defaultValue to stop the first 
                            value in the dropdown from showing which was unsuccessful also
                             to show but didn't work at all either
                         <option value="Cool School"> Cool School </option>
                         <option value="Another School">Another School </option>
                 <button className="btn btn-success btn-block mt-3 mb-5">Add</button>
              </form>
      )
}
```

Initially, the default school shows as the selected item in the dropdown; I click the add button and the school is not submitted. However, after the first click of the add button, the correct behavior occurs and each additional click submits the school. There are many SO posts regarding this issue but none include React and hooks or provide any insight on conditionally rendering a dropdown list default option.

Complete code example:

```
 import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
 //components
 import InputConnection from './connectionlist/InputConnection'
 import ListConnections from './connectionlist/ListConnections'
 import LogoutBtn from './LogoutBtn'
 import ReportingLayout from './reporting/Layout/ReportingLayout'

const Dashboard = ({ setAuth }) => {
const [name, setName] = useState("")
const [allConnections, setAllConnections] = useState([])
const [connectionsChange, setConnectionsChange] = useState(false)
const [timeDay, setTimeDay] = useState("Good Morning,")
const auth = setAuth

const getName = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("/dashboard/", {
            method:"GET", 
            headers:{ token: localStorage.token }
        })

        const parseData = await response.json()
        // console.log(parseData)
    if (parseData.admin === 'lead') {
        setName("Lead School Counselor")
        setAllConnections(parseData.results)
    }else{
        setName(parseData[0].user_name)
        setAllConnections(parseData)
    }
    } catch (error) {
    
    }
}

const greeting = () => {
    let date = new Date()
    const hours = date.getHours()
    if(hours < 12){
        setTimeDay("Good Morning, ")
    }else if (hours >= 12 && hours < 17){
        setTimeDay("Good Afternoon, ")
    }else{
        setTimeDay("Good Evening, ")
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    getName()
    greeting()
    setConnectionsChange(false)
}, [connectionsChange, timeDay])

if(name === "Lead School Counselor" ){
    return(
        <div>
            <ReportingLayout auth={auth} allConnections={ allConnections } />    
        </div>
       )
}else{
    let defaultSchool
    switch(name) {
      case 'Jim Smith':
        defaultSchool= "Cool School"
        break;
      case "Bob Williams":
        defaultSchool= "Another School"
        break;
  }

return(
    <Fragment>
        <div className="container">
            <div className='btn-group '>
                <LogoutBtn setAuth = {setAuth}/>
            </div>
                <h1 className="d-flex mt-3 pl-3" > {timeDay} 
    {name}&nbsp;&nbsp;</h1>
                <InputConnection defaultSchool={defaultSchool} 
setConnectionsChange={setConnectionsChange}/>
                <ListConnections allConnections={ allConnections } 
setConnectionsChange={setConnectionsChange}/> 
            </div>     
        </Fragment>
    )
}
}
```

export default Dashboard;

Next Component:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'

const InputTodo = ({ defaultSchool, setConnectionsChange }) => {

  const today = new Date()
  var formattedDate = today.toISOString().substr(0,10);
  const [contact_type, setContactType] = useState("");
  const [contact_method, setContactMethod] = useState("");
  const [provision, setProvision] = useState("");
  const [connection_date, setDate] = useState(formattedDate);
  const [student_id, setStudentID] = useState("");
  const [purpose, setPurpose] = useState("");
  const [gender, setGender] = useState("");
  const [yearGroup, setYearGroup] = useState("");
  const [referral_discharge, setReferralDischarge] = useState("");
  const [cp_referral, setCPReferral] = useState("");
  const [school, setSchool] = useState(defaultSchool);

  const onSubmitForm = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const myHeaders = new Headers();
      myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
      myHeaders.append("token", localStorage.token);

     const body = { 
                  contact_type, 
                  contact_method, 
                  provision,
                  connection_date,
                  student_id,
                  purpose,
                  gender,
                  yearGroup,
                  school, 
                  referral_discharge, 
                  cp_referral
                };
  const response = await fetch("/dashboard/connections", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  });

  const parseResponse = await response.json();

  console.count(parseResponse);

  setConnectionsChange(true);
  setContactType("")
  setContactMethod("")
  setProvision("")
  setDate(formattedDate)
  setStudentID("")
  setPurpose("")
  setGender("")
  setYearGroup("")
  setSchool(defaultSchool)
  setReferralDischarge("")
  setCPReferral("")

  toast.success('Contact has been added', {
    position: "top-center",
    autoClose: 3000,
    hideProgressBar: false,
    closeOnClick: true,
    pauseOnHover: true, 
    draggable: true,
    });

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
 };
return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="text-center my-5 input-title">Communication Log</h1>
      <form className="mt-5" onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
    {/* DATE  */}
    <input type="date"  name="connection_date" placeholder="Date of Contact" 
    className="form-control" value={connection_date} onChange={e => 
    setDate(e.target.value)}/>
    {/* SCHOOL  */}
    <select  type="text" name="school" placeholder="School" className="form- 
    control mt-3" defaultValue={defaultSchool} value={defaultSchool} 
    onChange={e => setSchool(e.target.value)}>
        <option value="NADA" disabled>Choose your school</option>
      <optgroup label= "SEN">
          <option value="Cool School">Cool SChool</option>
          <option value= "Another School">Another School</option>
      
      </optgroup>
    </select>
    {/* SCHOOL ID */}
    <input type="text" name="student_id" placeholder="Student ID" 
    className="form-control mt-3" value={student_id} onChange={e => 
    setStudentID(e.target.value)}/>
    {/* YEAR / GROUP  */}
    <select type="text" name="yeargroup" placeholder="year/group" 
className="form-control mt-3" value={yearGroup} onChange={e => 
setYearGroup(e.target.value)}>
      <option value="DEFAULT">Choose the Year/ Group</option>
      <option value="yr01">yr01</option>
      <option value="yr02">yr02</option>
      <option value="yr03">yr03</option>
      <option value="yr04">yr04</option>
      <option value="yr05">yr05</option>
      <option value="yr06">yr06</option>
      <option value="yr07">yr07</option>
      <option value="yr08">yr08</option>
      <option value="yr09">yr09</option>
      <option value="yr10">yr10</option>
      <option value="yr11">yr11</option>
      <option value="yr12">yr12</option>
    </select>
    {/* GENDER  */}
    <select type="text" name="gender" placeholder="gender" className="form-control mt-3" value={gender} onChange={e => setGender(e.target.value)}>
      <option value="DEFAULT">Gender</option>
      <option value="M">M</option>
      <option value="F">F</option>
    </select>
    {/* REFERRAL OR DISCHARGE */}
    <select type="text" name="referral_discharge" placeholder="referral_discharge" className="form-control mt-3" value={referral_discharge} onChange={e => setReferralDischarge(e.target.value)}>
      <option value="DEFAULT">Was this a referral, continuation or discharge?</option>
      <option value="referral">Referral</option>
      <option value="discharge">Discharge</option>
      <option value="continuation">Continuation</option>
    </select>
  
    {/* CONTACT TYPE  */}
    <select type="text" name="contact_type" placeholder="contact_type" className="form-control mt-3" value={contact_type} onChange={e => setContactType(e.target.value)}>
      <option value="DEFAULT">Type of Contact</option>
      <option value="student">student</option>
      <option value="parent">parent</option>
      <option value="emergeny contact">emergeny contact</option>
      <option value="staff">staff</option>
      <option value="social worker">social worker</option>
      <option value="support staff">support staff</option>
      <option value="SENCO">SENCO</option>
      <option value="other">other</option>
    </select>

    {/* CONTACT METHOD  */}
    <select type="text" name="contact_method" placeholder="contact_method" className="form-control mt-3" value={contact_method} onChange={e => setContactMethod(e.target.value)}>
    <option value ="DEFAULT">Contact Mode/ Method</option>
      <option value="in-person">in-person</option>
      <option value="text">text</option>
      <option value="whatsapp">whatsapp</option>
      <option value="phone call">phone call</option>
      <option value="email">email</option>
      <option value="check-in">check-in</option>
      <option value="classroom presentation">classroom presentation</option>
      <option value="session">session</option>
      <option value="video chat">video chat</option>
      <option value="group">group session</option>
      <option value="crisis intervention">crisis intervention</option>
      <option value="home visit">home visit</option>
      <option value="sbst, mdt, case conference">sbst, mdt, case conference</option> 
      <option value="outside agency meeting">outside agency meeting</option>
      <option value="other meeting">other meeting</option>
      
    </select>
    {/* CP_REFERRAL  */}
    <select type="text" name="cp_referral" placeholder="cp_referral" className="form-control mt-3" value={cp_referral} onChange={e => setCPReferral(e.target.value)}>
      <option value="DEFAULT">Was this a CP Referral?</option>
      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
    {/* <div className='mt-3'>
      <p>Is this a CP REFERRAL?</p>
      <div className="form-check-inline">
          <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="cp_referral" id="y" value={cp_referral} onClick={(e)=> setCp_referral(e.target.value)}/>
          <label className="form-check-label">Yes</label>
      </div>

      <div className="form-check-inline">
        <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="cp_referral" id="n" value={cp_referral} onClick={(e)=> setCp_referral(e.target.value)}/>
        <label className="form-check-label">No</label>
      </div>
    </div> */}
    {/* PURPOSE  */}
    <textarea className="form-control mt-3" name="purpose" placeholder="What was the purpose of the connection?" value={purpose} onChange={e => setPurpose(e.target.value)}></textarea>
    {/* PROVISION  */}
    <textarea className="form-control mt-3" name="provision" placeholder="Provision/Support Agreed Upon/ Plan Forward (When Necessary) / Any Additional Notes" value={provision} onChange={e => setProvision(e.target.value)}></textarea>
    {/* BUTTON  */}
    <button className="btn btn-success btn-block mt-3 mb-5">Add</button>
  </form>
</Fragment>
```

);
};

export default InputTodo;

Comment: Please share a complete code example.

Comment: Seems you are asking about at least a couple issues, please limit SO questions to a single specific issue and provide enough code for others to understand and see where the issue is. More code is better than not enough, but too much code is just as bad as not enough. I suspect your `useEffect` that is calling `greeting()` that is causing the render looping. `greeting` updates `timeDay` which is listed in the effect's dependency array, though it isn't clear why since it isn't used in the effect.

Comment: No main question is just why does it take two clicks before it behaves properly; that's it.

Comment: Is `name` always one of "Jim Smith" or "Bob Williams" *after* the initial render? `defaultSchool` is undefined on the initial render. What else is between `InputConnection` and `InputTodo`, or are they *actually* the same component? Can you clarify what you mean by the school being submitted or not? Are you simply clicking "add" a second time, with no interaction with the form fields, and the form is working as expected? Can you create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue before with dropdowns where I am manually setting the `value` prop.  What happens is that there's always going to be one option visible in the dropdown no matter what.  If a `value` is passed in then that value should be shown.  But if you pass in `undefined` then the first option in the list becomes the visible one.  It *looks like* that option is selected, but it's not actually selected.  That's why if you select another option and then go back to that first one it will work, because you've actually selected it now.

```
const [school, setSchool] = useState(defaultSchool)
```

The initial state of `useState` is set only one time.  It does not respond to changes in your `defaultSchool` prop.  So if it first receives a value of `undefined` then `school` will stay `undefined` until you call `setSchool`, even if you get a valid value for `defaultSchool` later on.

One way to get around this is to use a `useEffect` hook to listen for changes to defaultSchool.

```
useEffect( () => {
    if ( defaultSchool & ! school ) {
        setSchool( defaultSchool );
    }
}, [defaultSchool, school]);
```

Comment: This is what I was suspecting was occurring as well, though compounding the issue is the usage of both a `defaultValue` and `value` prop. With the `onChange` handler I assume OP wanted this to be a controlled input, and as such the value should reflect state and not the passed prop, i.e. it should be `value={school}`. By using `value={defaultSchool}` though the input would look like it changed (it would), but not the state, as you correctly point out.